# Excel: Only return complete once all five cells have a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a list of marketing preferences for our clients. I have 5 options, and I need each cell to be either Yes or No depending on the client's preferences. At the end of the row, I have a cell for 'Completed Preferences'.

I don't mind if the answer is Yes or No, but I want the 'Completed Preferences' to be 'Incomplete' if any data from the row is missing, and 'Complete' once all of the preferences have a Yes OR No value.

The database will have to be used by many people so I'm trying to make it as foolproof as possible by using text rather than numbers.

I've tried Googling, IF statements, ISBLANK statements, and I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **F1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,"Yes")+COUNTIF(A1:E1,"No")=5,"Completed Preferences","Incomplete")
```

They must all be filled in with either **Yes** or **No**.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using a combination of the [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), [`ISBLANK`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) and [`OR`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/orfunction-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) functions in Excel.

For example, if the cells you're referring to are cells `A1` through `E1`, this formula would work for you:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1), ISBLANK(B1), ISBLANK(C1), ISBLANK(D1), ISBLANK(E1)),"Incomplete", "Complete")
```

To step through this:

1. `ISBLANK(A1)`, `ISBLANK(B1)`, etc will give you `TRUE` if the cell is blank.
2. `OR(...)` will give you `TRUE` if any one of the items in 1. is blank.
3. `IF` 3. returns `TRUE`, this means that the work is incomplete. `IF` 3. returns `FALSE`, this means that the work is complete.

**Note:** This may not work if `A1` through `E1` contain functions that return "" (the cell is not blank in the technical sense, but doesn't contain any characters). In that case you would need to replace `ISBLANK(A1)` with `IF(A1<>"")` and so on.